# Recommendations for entity mapping and update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For simplicity sake I didn't include all the fields. But EmmPolicy entity is big (20+ properties).
The object is coming from an external API, so I can't really reduce the number of properties yet.
My problem is when I try to save the EmmPolicy object, the ApplicationPolicy objects in Set are also saved (as they should) but they don't have a foreign key to EmmPolicy.

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Table(name = "policy")
public class EmmPolicy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "policy", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ApplicationPolicy> applications = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "policy_application")
public class ApplicationPolicy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "policy_fk")
    private EmmPolicy policy;
}
```

I read that the possible solution might be using other id generation strategy. But SEQUENCE didn't really worked out for me. Right now I manually insert the EmmPolicy object into ApplicationPolicy on update:

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public List<EmmPolicy> savePolicies(List<Policy> googlePolicies) {
        LOGGER.info("Syncing policies");

        List<EmmPolicy> forSavePolicies = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Policy policy : googlePolicies) {

            EmmPolicy fromDbPolicy = repo.findByName(policy.getName()).orElse(null);
            if (fromDbPolicy == null) {
                EmmPolicy emmPolicy = mapGoogleObjectToEntity(policy);
                forSavePolicies.add(emmPolicy);

                //TODO SUPER BAD if possible find another way
                Set<ApplicationPolicy> apps = emmPolicy.getApplications();
                if (apps != null) {
                    for (ApplicationPolicy app : apps) {
                        app.setPolicy(emmPolicy);
                    }
                }

                Set<PersistentPreferredActivity> activities = emmPolicy.getPersistentPreferredActivities();
                if (activities != null) {
                    for (PersistentPreferredActivity activity : activities) {
                        activity.setPolicy(emmPolicy);
                    }
                }

                continue;
            }
            
            mapper.map(policy, fromDbPolicy);
            forSavePolicies.add(fromDbPolicy);

        }

        return repo.saveAll(forSavePolicies);
    }


    public EmmPolicy mapGoogleObjectToEntity(Policy policy) {
       return mapper.map(policy, EmmPolicy.class);
    }
```

I know it stinks but couldn't come up with anything else.